# How can I perform a 1:1 sequence-structure alignment for a pdb template dimer and homologous dimer sequence?

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, computational-model, pdb

I have:
1. A PDB dimer protein structure template of a real solved protein.
2. An unsolved, but highly homologous dimer protein (>90% sequence identity.)

How can I use MODELLER to make a theoretical model of my dimer of unknown structure, using the homologous dimer template?

I know I need a PIR alignment file, probably with a 1:1 sequence-structure alignment.  However, I do not know how to make this file.

Please advise?